# TikZ not showing up image in VS Code, latest Mac OS, latest MacTex distribution (Freshly installed 2022 using the .pkg)

Tags: tikz-pgf, vscode

I was wondering why thee images are not showing up.

For the code
From :https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/TikZ_package

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[gray, thick] (-1,2) -- (2,-4);
\draw[gray, thick] (-1,-1) -- (2,2);
\filldraw[black] (0,0) circle (2pt) node[anchor=west]{Intersection point};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I receive this image
[image]
LATEX workshop in VS code is also installed.

I received an error message.

```
Rc files read:
  /Users/nasa_william_lu/.latexmkrc
Latexmk: Run number 1 of rule 'latex'
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=latex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
Latexmk: If appropriate, the -f option can be used to get latexmk
  to try to force complete processing.
Latexmk: Getting log file 'out/LaTeX Solution Template.log'
Latexmk: Log file says no output from latex
Latexmk: For rule 'latex', no output was made
Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
  latex: Command for 'latex' gave return code 1
      Refer to 'out/LaTeX Solution Template.log' for details
```

The picture is rendered perfectly in OverLeaf.
[image]

All the other materials are rendered just fine. All my texts, equations, tables are all correct.

This problem didn't happen a week ago. During this week, I think I updated it once using `sudo tlmgr update --self && sudo tlmgr update --all`. That's when it stopped working.

So I uninstalled the current `2022` version and install the latest `2022` from MacTex `.pkg` installer.

Thank you so much for your time reading this. Really appreciate any help!

UPDATE: **THE CODE cannot produce any images in VS Code but can produce images in TexShop**
[image]

UPDATE: I added the following to the `settings.json` file

```
{
// your other settings
// ...
// ...
// ---------- Language ----------
    "[tex]": {
        // Enable intellisence/quick suggestions
        "editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions": false,
        // Indentation size
        "editor.tabSize": 2
    },
    "[latex]": {
        // Enable intellisence/quick suggestions
        "editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions": false,
        // Indentation size
        "editor.tabSize": 2
    },
    "[bibtex]": {
        // Indentation size
        "editor.tabSize": 2
    },
    // ---------- LaTeX Workshop ----------
    //  Enable command and environment completion for used package
    "latex-workshop.intellisense.package.enabled": true,
    // target file when deleting generated file
    // Add "* .synctex.gz" to default value
    "latex-workshop.latex.clean.fileTypes": [
        "*.aux",
        "*.bbl",
        "*.blg",
        "*.idx",
        "*.ind",
        "*.lof",
        "*.lot",
        "*.out",
        "*.toc",
        "*.acn",
        "*.acr",
        "*.alg",
        "*.glg",
        "*.glo",
        "*.gls",
        "*.ist",
        "*.fls",
        "*.log",
        "*.fdb_latexmk",
        "*.snm",
        "*.nav",
        "*.dvi",
        "*.synctex.gz"
    ],
    // dump generated files to "out" directory
    "latex-workshop.latex.outDir": "out",
    // Build recipe
    "latex-workshop.latex.recipes": [
        {
            "name": "latexmk",
            "tools": [
                "latexmk"
            ]
        },
    ],
    // Parts used in the build recipe
    "latex-workshop.latex.tools": [
        {
            "name": "latexmk",
            "command": "latexmk",
            "args": [
                "-silent",
                "-outdir=%OUTDIR%",
                "%DOC%"
            ],
        },
    ],
}
```

as per this site: https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-auto-update-pdf-when-working-on-latex-ad9eeabdb7a1

Comment: What does the .log file contains when you try with VS Code? You have this output: `Latexmk: Getting log file 'out/LaTeX Solution Template.log'` and `Refer to 'out/LaTeX Solution Template.log' for details`. Try to find relevant messages in it.

Comment: $quark67 problem solved. Thank you!

Comment: You could write an answer to your question if you have find the error in the log file and how you have resolved it, so this can be useful for others.

Comment: @quark67 Thanks for your suggestion! Actually this is my first answer. It feels great helping others.

Answer (score 3):

The solution to this problem: something wrong with the LaTex Workshop environment.

This applies to you if you have a:

- mac os latest as of 2023 March
- VSCode
- LaTex workshop in VS code installed
- MacTex installed

And most importantly, you have added extra settings to enable automatic pdfLaTex compile **as per this site**  https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-auto-update-pdf-when-working-on-latex-ad9eeabdb7a1.

The site comprises two parts:

1. `nano` and modify the LaTex behavior
2. Modify the `settings.json` file within VS Code

It turns out, that it's the 2. that prevents `TikZ` from being compiled. While the root of the cause has not been located, it is advisable that you only do the `1.` according to the tutorial on that site and do **Not** modify the LaTeX workshop settings in VS Code via the `settings.json` file.

The ultimate result is that although `2.` was deleted, the LaTex file can still automatically compile, albeit slightly less responsively.